# Find all $t$ where coplanar

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What are all real $t$ such that the vectors $a=<1,2,3>, b=<2,5,8>, c=<1,1,t>$ are coplanar.

What I thought:

I thought to find when $a\cdot (b \times c)=0$ However, the $t$ is throwing me off. Can someone help me here?
I found it to be only at t=1, am I right?

Comment: An alternative to doing it via cross products is to ask: Can I write one of the vectors in terms of the other two? If not, they can't be co-planar. Since all three vectors definitely point in different directions, it's enough to pick one of them and see when it's possible versus not.

Comment: @Semiclassical So is my answer correct? At t=1 only?

Comment: @Semiclassical What did you get? Can you provide a solution if possible?

Comment: Actually, you're right---I made an error of my own in claiming otherwise.

Comment: @Semiclassical So is that the only one, or are there more?

Comment: Think about the geometry: The first two vectors form a plane. You then take a third vector, whose $x-$ and $y-$ components are known, and vary the $z$-component. How many times could that third vector possibly be coplanar?

Comment: @Semiclassical once